# binding the selected value from a dropdown to a span element using subscribe function

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to figure out how the subscribe function in knockout works and I am hoping someone can help me out. I am basically trying to take the selected value from an array and bind it to a span element using `subscribe()`

I was hoping to do this without involving awareness of the ui by using a selector or some other event. Based upon what I read from the documentation subscribe should update the value as items are selected. I'm missing something here as I cannot get anything to bind to the span tag.

I'd appreciate any comments on what I am missing.

thanks

Code and fiddle below
[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rlcrews/tJmwp/)

js

```
var myProduceModel = function(){
 var self = this;


    self.produceList = ko.observableArray([
        {productName: "Apples", productCode: "#FF0000"},
        {productName: "Oranges", productCode: "#FF9200"},
        {productName: "Grapes", productCode: "#652C90"},
        {productName: "Figs", productCode: "#67070D"}    
        ]);

    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    self.selectedField = ko.observable();

    self.selectedItem.subscribe(function(item){
        self.selectedField(item.productName);
        return item.productCode;
    });
};

    ko.applyBindings(new myProduceModel());
```

htm

```
<select data-bind="options: produceList, optionsText:'productName', optionsvalue: 'selectedItem', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>

<hr/>
<span data-bind="text: selectedItem().productCode"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing the `selectedValue` option which is used to tell which property of your object to use as the selected value.

To set the selected value itself you to need use the `value` binding.

So change your bindings to:

```
<select data-bind="options: produceList, 
                   optionsText:'productName', 
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
                   value: selectedItem"></select>
```

Demo [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8j7p/).

You had one additional problem in your fiddle the `data-bind="text: selectedItem().productCode"` will fail if nothing is selected. So you need something like
`data-bind="text: selectedItem() && selectedItem().productCode"` or use the `with` binding.